# iOS app seems to think its width is half of what it really is

Tags: ios, swift, width, skshapenode

In my iOS swift app I have an instance where I am making a circle with SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15) but it makes a skinny ellipse instead, the width is only half of what it should be to make a circle.

Also, when I try to put something in the middle of the screen by setting the position.x of the object to view.bounds.width/2 it puts it in the middle of the left half of the screen instead of the middle of the whole screen. When I try to put it on the far right of the screen by using position.x to view.bounds.width it then goes to the middle instead of the right bound of the screen.

Has anyone ever seen this and know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the view which you are adding the SKShapeNode to. It may be that your scene was created to half of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things you can checkout here first.

1. i didnt add the view's view controller as a child view controller before loading the view. That fixed this issue for me.
2. Check the frame of the superview before you're adding the view as its subview, when i seen the frame isnt what i thoguht it was number one solved my problem
3. the last thing i can think of is add this code to layout subviews. Layout Subviews is called once all the on screen view's bounds and frames have been updated.

If all three doesnt work. Then smoewhere in your code your not doing something right. Displaying some code that you have wrote can dramatically help us help you. Good Speed my friend God Speed.